# Jaxb deserialization with access to Spring beans

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I have my model, which looks something like that:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Foo {
    private List<Bar> bars;

    //getters and setters..
}
```

I would like to deserialize object of class Foo from xml, but problem is, that to instatiate class Bar I need my spring-congigured service and one property of Bar object(from prior serialization).

As far as I know, I cannot use XmlAdapter(no access to spring beans), and I cannot serialize Bars directly(no access to spring beans and moreover, calling service from model layer is not something I would like to do).

Is ther any simple way of doing this? I would like also not to add AspectJ only for injecting spring beans to XmlAdapter.

Comment: That sounds strange to me. Why do you need a spring-configured service  to instantiate a model class from a serialized version?

Comment: It is wrapper for JarFile from which I read source files, compile it at runtime, load classes and save them in this wrapper. A lot of code I cannot duplicate or ignore.